# ROS turtlesim - not responding to keyboard

Tags: ros, communication, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I just got started with ROS, and I bumped into the first wall when I was going through the tutorial in running turtlesim.

After I ran 'roscore', 'rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node' and 'rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key', it went through the settings fine. However, it is not responding to my keyboard control. I selected the terminal window of the turtle_teleop_key, but no luck.

While running them, I ran rxgraph to see the diagram, but it mentioned that the node communication failed, so I am predicting it's the problem with network setting, but I don't know how to fix it.

I would greatly appreciate for your help.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46140/ros-turtlesim---not-responding-to-keyboard/) by [daikii](https://answers.ros.org/users/3405/daikii/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on 2017-09-01**:
Are you able to move it via manually publishing to the turtlesim_node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's hard to help without further information. As a first step, have a look at the [network setup page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup). `rosnode info teleop_turtle` might also provide some information.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ### current program

- put your mouse cursor on the terminal (which make it the current program to accept keys), and try to move your turtle again.
- The problem may because you put your turtlesim at the most front, but turtlesim is not the true one to accept keys.

---

Originally posted by [wangzheqie](https://answers.ros.org/users/32120/wangzheqie/) with karma: 11 on 2017-10-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1